# Format quantmod GetSymbol data so that multiple Symbols are in one data frame

Tags: r, finance, quantmod, quantitative-finance

I have some stock data that is formatted like this (got it from another source):

```
 Company,Date,Close
 AXP,2011-06-03,49.28
 AXP,2011-06-04,49.28
 CAT,2011-06-03,101.1
 CAT,2011-06-04,101.1
```

What I want to do is add the volume to that. If you download stock data using the `GetSymbols` command, volume is part of it.

The problem is that data obtained using the `GetSymbols` command is structured completely differently. See:

[image: GetSymbols]

Would it somehow be possible to change the format so that I have the data in the above format? I want to the outcome table to look like this:

```
 Company,Date,Close,Volume
 AXP,2011-06-03,49.28,5000000
 AXP,2011-06-04,49.28,3500000
 CAT,2011-06-03,101.1,1000000
 CAT,2011-06-04,101.1,3000000
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Two things are not clear. 1. Where to get `AXP` and `CAT` info? 2. Date is not matching at all. One place its 2011 and another place its 2007. How to link?

Comment: 1. I have separate tables for `AXP`, `CAT` and other information. 2. Date goes from 2007 until 2018, it was just an example. My problem is basically that I want to put all these separate tables in one table and add a column with `AXP`, `CAT` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you can do it:

- create vector of tickers
- initiate a new empty dataframe with column names corresponding with original data frame

loop over ticker symbols:

- fortify the xts created by `getSymbols` and extract the volume column and add a new `Company` column
- `rbind` tickers
- `merge` original dataframe with new dataframe by `Company,Date` columns

The code snippet assumes that your imported Data is a `dataframe` object and named `dfOrig`

```
tickers <- c('AXP','CAT')
getSymbols(c("AXP","CAT"), from = '2018-03-01')
dfNew <- data.frame(Company = character(),
                 Date=as.Date(character()),
                 Close=numeric(),
                 Volume=numeric(), 
                 stringsAsFactors=FALSE) 
for(i in 1:length(tickers)){
  dfSym <- cbind(Company=rep(tickers[i],nrow(get(tickers[i]))),fortify.zoo(get(tickers[i])[,5]))
  names(dfSym)[2:3] <- c('Date','Volume')
  dfNew <- rbind(dfNew,dfSym)
}
```

The first few lines from `dfNew`:

```
> head(dfNew)
  Company       Date  Volume
1     AXP 2018-03-01 4369800
2     AXP 2018-03-02 3584700
3     AXP 2018-03-05 2661400
4     AXP 2018-03-06 3221100
5     AXP 2018-03-07 3594900
6     AXP 2018-03-08 3760500
```

Now you can merge the dataframes by `Company` and`Date`.

```
> merge(dfOrig,dfNew,by = intersect(names(dfOrig), names(dfNew)))
   Company       Date  Close   Volume
1      AXP 2018-03-01  95.14  4369800
2      AXP 2018-03-02  95.60  3584700
3      AXP 2018-03-05  96.66  2661400
4      AXP 2018-03-06  96.07  3221100
5      AXP 2018-03-07  95.64  3594900
6      AXP 2018-03-08  96.59  3760500
7      AXP 2018-03-09  99.05  3044300
8      AXP 2018-03-12  97.67  4020900
9      AXP 2018-03-13  95.37  4858700
10     AXP 2018-03-14  94.53  3013800
11     AXP 2018-03-15  94.39  3213000
12     AXP 2018-03-16  95.61  5124900
13     AXP 2018-03-19  94.84  2610400
14     AXP 2018-03-20  94.95  2501600
15     AXP 2018-03-21  94.74  2124000
16     AXP 2018-03-22  91.41  4113900
17     AXP 2018-03-23  90.45  5100400
18     AXP 2018-03-26  92.62  2769800
19     AXP 2018-03-29  93.28  4914600
20     CAT 2018-03-01 150.23  9434800
21     CAT 2018-03-02 146.38  9509400
22     CAT 2018-03-05 151.12  8453000
23     CAT 2018-03-06 153.75  5795600
24     CAT 2018-03-07 151.51  5491000
25     CAT 2018-03-08 153.59  4105000
26     CAT 2018-03-09 158.25  4576700
27     CAT 2018-03-12 154.50  4880400
28     CAT 2018-03-13 153.69  4819100
29     CAT 2018-03-14 152.54  4873600
30     CAT 2018-03-15 154.57  5268800
31     CAT 2018-03-16 156.46 10897600
32     CAT 2018-03-19 152.15  5479200
33     CAT 2018-03-20 154.06  3557600
34     CAT 2018-03-21 155.80  3887400
35     CAT 2018-03-22 146.90  8225600
36     CAT 2018-03-23 144.29  6533100
37     CAT 2018-03-26 149.19  5454900
38     CAT 2018-03-27 146.99  4915300
39     CAT 2018-03-28 145.16  4933900
40     CAT 2018-03-29 147.38  4179000
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `tidyquant` for this:

```
library(tidyquant)

ticks <- c("AXP","CAT")
sd <- as.Date("2011-06-03")
ed <- as.Date("2011-06-10")

tq_get(ticks, 
       from = sd, 
       to = ed ) %>%
  select(symbol, date, close,volume) %>% 
  arrange(date)
```